# Rails and Rake : .rakeTasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

What is `.rakeTasks` file for ?

Rails version : 3.2.1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `.rakeTasks` file is created by the [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) [Ruby plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&pluginId=1293) (and possibly by JetBrains' Ruby-specific [RubyMine](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) IDE as well, I'm not sure). As the comments in the file itself state:

```
<!--This file was automatically generated by Ruby plugin.
You are allowed to: 
1. Remove rake task
2. Add existing rake tasks
To add existing rake tasks automatically delete this file and reload the project.
-->
```

It provides the list of Rake tasks that appears when you select **Tools / Run Rake Task...**:

[image]

Unless you need to customize that list for some reason, you probably never need to edit the file. Personally I exclude it from version control in my `.gitignore`, along with the `.ipr`, `.iml`, and `.iws` files. (I might check it in if I was working in a homogeneous IDEA shop, but I'm not.)

Answer (score 0):

This file are auto-require and define you project specific task accessible by rake.

Comment: Does it have to be commited on the SVC ?

Comment: What is the purpose of this file? It's automatically created, but what creates it and why?

Comment: @lepnio Not unless you need to customize it and share it with other IDEA/RubyMine users; see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28909057/27358).